# Send post request with cookies [python]

Tags: python, http

```
POST /search HTTP/1.1
Host: chatango.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: cookies_enabled.chatango.com=yes; fph.chatango.com=http; id.chatango.com=programmable; auth.chatango.com={MY AUTH KEY - I already have this}
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://st.chatango.com/flash/sellers_external.swf
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 27

s=B&ama=99&ami=13&t=25&f=20
```

I'd really like to know how to send this via python, I haven't found anything except sending that data part, I really don't understand how I'm supposed to send the cookie data as I have it stored into a variable which I got through an API, which obtains it through sockets.

Comment: have you looked at the requests module? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.0/user/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

You can add new headers in the `request()` method:

```
HTTPConnection.request(method, url[, body[, headers]])
```

See [request documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httpconnection-objects).

To add a cookie, just add the Cookie header.

Here is a POST example from the [Python site](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/httplib-examples.html):

```
import httplib, urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           "Accept": "text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("musi-cal.mojam.com:80")
conn.request("POST", "/cgi-bin/query", params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
conn.close()
```